# C++: Classic undefined symbols for architecture error

Tags: c++

Learning C++ lately, and I'm having trouble to compile my classes. I am currently getting the following obscure template error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SmallWorld::AJV::validate(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>*, nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>*)", referenced from:
      SmallWorld::Map::(anonymous namespace)::readMap(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in map.test.cpp.o
  "std::__1::function<unsigned long (SmallWorld::Map::Graph<SmallWorld::Region>)> SmallWorld::Map::algorithm::dfs<SmallWorld::Region>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::function<bool (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > > > const&)> const&)", referenced from:
      creates_a_connected_graph_small_world_map_Test::TestBody() in map.test.cpp.o
  "SmallWorld::Region::Region(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>)", referenced from:
      std::__1::shared_ptr<SmallWorld::Region> std::__1::shared_ptr<SmallWorld::Region>::make_shared<nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&>(nlohmann::basic_json<std::__1::map, std::__1::vector, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, long long, unsigned long long, double, std::__1::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer> const&&&) in map.test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

which can be simplified to:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SmallWorld::AJV::validate(nlohmann::json*, nlohmann::json*)", referenced from:
      SmallWorld::Map::(anonymous namespace)::readMap(string const&, string const&) in map.test.cpp.o
  "std::function<size_t(Graph<Region>)> SmallWorld::Map::algorithm::dfs<SmallWorld::Region>(string const&, std::function<bool (string const&, std::set<string> const&, std::unordered_map<string, string> const&)", referenced from:
      creates_a_connected_graph_small_world_map_Test::TestBody() in map.test.cpp.o
  "SmallWorld::Region::Region(nlohmann::json)", referenced from:
      std::shared_ptr<SmallWorld::Region> std::shared_ptr<SmallWorld::Region>::make_shared<nlohmann::json const&&&) in map.test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Which to me seems like it is saying that the method `bool AJV::validate(json* schema, json* data)` does not exist on type AJV. However I have verified the common mistakes (different implementation from header declaration, different invocation from implementation), to no avail.

Here is the definition and implementation of the AJV class:

```
// AJV.h
#ifndef SMALLWORLD_AJV_H
#define SMALLWORLD_AJV_H

#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using nlohmann::json;

namespace SmallWorld {
  class AJV {
  public:
    std::function<bool(json*)> compile(json* schema);
    bool validate(json* schema, json* data);
    json errors;
  private:
    json m_schema;
    std::function<bool(json*)> m_validator;
  };
};

#endif // SMALLWORLD_AJV_H

// AJV.cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include "AJV.h"

using nlohmann::json;

namespace SmallWorld {
  std::function<bool(json*)> AJV::compile(json* schema) {
    return [](json* data){ return true; };
  };
  bool AJV::validate(json* schema, json* data){ return true; };
};
```

And here is the invocation:

```
//loader.cpp
json* readMap(const string& map_path, const string& schema_path) {
        AJV ajv;
        json* schema = readJSONFile(schema_path);
        json* jmap = readJSONFile(map_path);
        if(ajv.validate(schema, jmap)){
          delete schema;
          return jmap;
        }else{
          delete schema;
          throw ajv.errors;
        }
      };
```

**Setup:**

- **OS:** MacOS 10.13.3
- **C++ Version:** 14
- **Compiler:** g++ => Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
- **Build manager:** CMake 3.5.1
- **IDE:** Atom IDE w/ linter-clang for linting (not really an IDE XD)

**Additional Details**

Compilation is done via command line: `mkdirp build && cd build && cmake .. && make`

File AJV.h is within source tree at the specified include path.

How can I solve this problem?

Cheers ☀️

Comment: You do build with the `AJV.cpp` source file? Or link with the object file created from that source file? How do you build your program? From the command line? What command do you use? Or do you use an IDE? Is the `AJV.cpp` source file in the IDE source tree?

Comment: You've got a `using namespace std` at the top - probably - we can see from your `string` ... and then you have a variable called map.  This isn't going to end well

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added the additional details requested :)

Comment: @UKMonkey You are totally right! I updated the variables to "jmap" and "data". No change in the error message though

Comment: If you have undefined symbols; but your functions are there; then your cmake file is probably wrong; make sure that it's compiling all the c++ files

Comment: Great find! That solved this error message. Now I get the same error for my test build. Is there a way to tell CMake to automatically follow the dependency tree and include any *.cpp files that match the .h files that are loaded by the build-included files?

Comment: The problem with that is that header files are not really tied to source files. CMake sets up dependencies for the header files you include in your *listed* source files, but but since there's really no connection from a header file to a specific source file, that link can't really be made. You have to explicitly list all source files you want to build with.

Comment: That's a shame :P I would have thought that someone would have added an opt-in setting in build systems that assume that for each .h file there is an equivalent .cpp file, and if not then the implementation is in the .h file. I guess I was wrong in assuming that :P

Comment: @UKMonkey if you want you can submit your comment as an answer; I can also answer my own question with a diff between my previous and current CMake file. Up to you. Cheers!

Comment: @PhilippeHebert glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register a project in CMake, you list both headers and source files.  It will then deal with these as best it can for the respective IDE / build system that you tell it to use.

If you always have one header and one cpp file (there's no requirement to; you may find some objects are complex/large enough that you want to split it into multiple cpp files for your sanity) then you could list all your file names with no extension in the cmake and have it append the .cxx and .h to the end for you.  This will leave you with just half the typing.

As an alternative there is a non-recommended route which is to to use the file command to scan the directory for files - but this is done only when cmake is run; and as such will not auto-update; leaving it possible to have a source tree that's building fine on one system; while not on another.